# Hiding submenus in an animated sidebar

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create an animated sidebar using CSS and JS, and I'm having an issue with hiding submenus (green in the [demo](https://codepen.io/lbastos/pen/eYYrwxw)). So, the submenus should fly out slowly like it is now, but only when parent `<li>` is hovered. Currently, they are always present. Also, list items below the hovered `<li>` should move down appropriately. In this scenario, when 'Transactions' is hovered, transactions submenu should appear slowly and take up space so 'Budgets' moves down accordingly. I have tried something with `display: none;` and `display: block;` but I've read that animations don't work on `display` property and couldn't get it to work, and I would really like to keep the animation. I have also tried something with `visibility` but failed, not worth mentioning.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('nav > ul > li');

  function onListItemClick() {
    for (let listItem of listItems) {
      listItem.classList.remove('active');
      listItem.children[0].classList.remove('dot');
      if (listItem.children.length > 2) {
        listItem.children[2].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
    this.classList.add('active');
    this.children[0].classList.add('dot');
    if (this.children.length > 2) {
      this.children[2].style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
  listItems.forEach(function(listItem) {
    listItem.addEventListener('click', onListItemClick);
  });
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10em 0 0 0;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25px 1fr;
  color: #959595;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li>span:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 3em;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li>span:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 3em;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li:hover {
  color: #757575;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li>ul {
  z-index: 9;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all 0.5 ease;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li:hover>ul {
  transform: translateY(30%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li>ul>li {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #33ad93;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0 0 0 5.5em;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li>ul>li:first-child {
  padding: 0.5em 0 0 5.5em;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li>ul>li:last-child {
  padding: 0 0 0.5em 5.5em;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li>ul>li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  padding: 0.15em 0 0.15em 5.5em;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li>ul>li>a {
  color: white;
}

.sidebar>nav>ul>li>span>a {
  color: #959595;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dot {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #33ad93;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}

.active {
  color: black !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class=" active ">
        <span class=" dot "></span>
        <span><a href="/dashboard/">Dashboard</a></span>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <span class=""></span>
        <span>Transactions</span>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/transactions/create/">New Transaction</a></li>
          <li>View Transactions</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <span class=""></span>
        <span>Budgets</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

How can I overcome the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I made a few small changes which seems to accomplish what you want:

```css
.sidebar > nav > ul > li > ul {
    z-index: 9;
    /*position: absolute;  *removed*/
    height: 0; /*added*/
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 300px;
    /*transform: translateY(0);  *removed*/
    /*transition: all 0.5 ease;  *removed*/
    overflow-y: hidden; /*added*/
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
    /*transform: translateY(30%);  *removed*/
    height: 80px; /*added*/
    transition: height 0.5s ease; /*modified*/
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    height: 40px; /*added*/
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #33ad93;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 0 0 5.5em;
}
```

So I added a static height to each of the new dropdown's list items to 40px, then set the container to 80px. Then we transition the height rather than the Y position. If you want it to be dynamic relative to the number of elements, unfortunately it's not as easy as using `height: 100%` instead of `height: 80px` (you'll need to use some javascript to dynamically set the height relative to the number of list items; it will still work, but the transition will be slightly broken).

Hopefully this should give you an idea though

Answer (score 0):

You have just missed unit for transition on default `ul`.

Here is updated code

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('nav > ul > li');
  function onListItemClick() {
    for (let listItem of listItems) {
      listItem.classList.remove('active');
      listItem.children[0].classList.remove('dot');
      if (listItem.children.length > 2) {
        listItem.children[2].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
    this.classList.add('active');
    this.children[0].classList.add('dot');
    if (this.children.length > 2) {
      this.children[2].style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
  listItems.forEach(function(listItem) {
    listItem.addEventListener('click', onListItemClick);
  });
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10em 0 0 0;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25px 1fr;
    color: #959595;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li > span:nth-child(1) {
    margin-left: 3em;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li > span:nth-child(2) {
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 3em;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li:hover {
    color: #757575;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li > ul {
    z-index: 0;
    height: 0px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 300px;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #33ad93;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 0 0 5.5em;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li > ul > li:first-child {
    padding: 0.5em 0 0 5.5em;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li > ul > li:last-child {
    padding: 0 0 0.5em 5.5em;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li > ul > li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    padding: 0.15em 0 0.15em 5.5em;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.sidebar > nav > ul > li > span > a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dot {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #33ad93;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}

.active {
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class=" active ">
        <span class=" dot "></span>
        <span><a href="/dashboard/">Dashboard</a></span>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <span class=""></span>
        <span>Transactions</span>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/transactions/create/">New Transaction</a></li>
          <li>View Transactions</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <span class=""></span>
        <span>Budgets</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the w3schools W3.CSS Framework page on [CSS Sidebars](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_sidebar.asp).

The snippet below is an example using that framework. You can then tweak it to your style from there.

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-light-grey w3-card">
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Dashboard</a>
  <div class="w3-dropdown-hover">
    <button class="w3-button">Transactions
                <span style="font-size:12px;padding-bottom:2px">&#9660;</span>
            </button>
    <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block" style="box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0.5em #00000040;">
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">New Transaction</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">View Transactions</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Budgets</a>
</div>
```